# Visualizing largish directed acyclic graphs (trees, networks) for Linux

Tags: linux, data-visualization

I have a data in form of CSV files:

```
Source,Target
1,2
1,3
2,4
2,5
2,6
3,7
```

that translate to directed acyclic graph/tree structure:

```
      1
    /   \
   2     3
 / | \    \
4  5  6    7
```

I need to visualize it. I need a tool that:

- handles largish data (hundreds of thousands to millions of rows),
- the visualizations are zoomable (since the tree will be large - multiple levels, many branches for each node),
- preferably, it should allow for folding/unfolding the branches.

The form of visualizations does not need to be pretty, it needs to be usable and readable.

I already tried graphviz, but it is very slow and what it returns for me is a black, unreadable blob--that's the reason I want something zoomable rather then a static graphic.

Comment: Did you try GraphViz's SVG export? Then you can magnify the image without loss of detail.

Comment: @Kodiologist I tried, but the files are pretty huge and still cluttered (this possibly can be improved by editing settings, but it rather doesn't work for me).